# Format .NET DateTime "Day" with no leading zero

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

For the following code, I would expect *result* to equal 2, because the MSDN states that 'd' "Represents the day of the month as a number from 1 through 31. A single-digit day is formatted without a leading zero.".

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime( 2009, 6, 4 );
string result = myDate.ToString( "d" );
```

However, *result* is actually equal to '6/4/2009' - which is the short-date format (which is also 'd'). I could use 'dd', but that adds a leading zero, which I don't want.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To indicate that this is a custom format specifier (in contrast to a standard format specifier), it must be two characters long. This can be accomplished by adding a space (which will show up in the output), or by including a percent sign before the single letter, like this:

```
string result = myDate.ToString("%d");
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#UsingSingleSpecifiers)

Answer (score 7):

Rather than using string formatting strings, how about using the Day property

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(2009,6,4)
int result = myDate.Day;
```

Or if you really needed the result in string format

```
string result = myDate.Day.ToString();
```

If you are looking to get a specific date part out of a date object rather than a formatted representation of the date, I prefer to use the properties (Day, Month, Year, DayOfWeek, etc.) It makes reading the code a bit easier (particularly if someone else is reading/maintaining it that doesn't have the various formatting codes memorized)

Comment: Thanks, you make a good point. Unfortunately in my case today I needed to put the format string in a property sheet as part of a report layout - so I had to use the %d value.