# C# ToString("MM/dd/yy") remove leading 0's

Tags: c#, date, tostring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format .NET DateTime “Day” with no leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988353/format-net-datetime-day-with-no-leading-zero)

Is there a way to remove the leading zeros in the date format

For example, `X.ToString("MM/dd/yy")` returns 07/02/11 but I'd like it to instead return 7/2/11.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: [Possible duplciate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988353/format-net-datetime-day-with-no-leading-zero)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: @Peter K. - Thanks I did not see that in my search. Is it proper to delete this since the answer is posted elsewhere?

Comment: @Evan: No, because it has answers, you won't be able to delete it.  The normal process seems to have taken its course, and the closure has been voted on. No worries!  That's the way SO works.

Comment: @Peter - Okay thanks. Hopefully my question will be easier to find for others looking for the answer though :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`X.ToString("M/d/yy")`     is what you need

Comment: is `d/M/yyyy` not a valid format?

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the extra `M` and `d`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `"M/d/yy"`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `X.ToString("M/d/yy")`

Answer (score 1):

It is `X.ToString("M/d/y")` if you want to remove ALL leading zeroes ;)