# @Html.DisplayFor - DateFormat ("mm/dd/yyyy")

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following razor code that I want to have `mm/dd/yyyy` date format:

```
Audit Date: @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.AuditDate)
```

I have tried number of different approaches but none of that approaches works in my situation

my AuditDate is a `DateTime?` type

I have tried something like this and got this error:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.AuditDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
```

Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Tried this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.AuditDate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 194):

If you use `DisplayFor`, then you have to either define the format via the `DisplayFormat` attribute or use a custom display template. (A full list of preset `DisplayFormatString`'s can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx).)

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime? AuditDate { get; set; }
```

Or create the view `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\DateTime.cshtml`:

```
@model DateTime?
@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    @Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
}
```

That will apply to all `DateTime`s, though, even ones where you're encoding the time as well. If you want it to apply only to date-only properties, then use `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Date.cshtml` and the `DataType` attribute on your property:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? AuditDate { get; set; }
```

The final option is to not use `DisplayFor` and instead render the property directly:

```
@if (Model.AuditDate.HasValue)
{
    @Model.AuditDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
}
```

Comment: I have created a displayTemplate as you suggested and when I copy and paste the code you have in template then I'm getting this error `No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: I think that should be `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]`

Comment: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")] worked for Turkey thanks

Comment: @Mac: How do you mean? They very much *do* work, but perhaps just not in your specific scenario. Without more information, I cannot say what your situations is.

Comment: If you want the editor to use the format aswell, add `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` to the property: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`. It should be obvious, but when you are all no-time-to-waste-copy-paste that hint from intellisense might go past your nose as it did mine :)

Comment: Yes, but in modern web development, you should almost never actually use that. If you're using the HTML5 input types (and you should), then the edit format *must* be ISO, which is  pretty much never the actual format you would also display to the user. This is yet another reason to use view models: to customize the format for the situation.

Answer (score 25):

I have been using this change in my code :

old code :

```
 <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dataakt)
 </td>
```

new :

```
<td>
 @Convert.ToDateTime(item.dataakt).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
</td>
```

Comment: ... and? Is this an answer or what?

Comment: Yes, it is simply solution to problem from subject . I thought this might be helpful to someone.

Comment: OK, I'd suggest you change "I have been using this change in my code " to something specifically stating that this is a solution.

Comment: Simple and convenient answer, worked for me thanks!!

Comment: Problem if dataakt is of type DateTime?

Answer (score 20):

If you are simply outputting the value of that model property, you don't need the `DisplayFor` html helper, just call it directly with the [proper string formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`Audit Date: @Model.AuditDate.Value.ToString("d")`

Should output

`Audit Date: 1/21/2015`

Lastly, your audit date could be null, so you should do the conditional check before you attempt to format a nullable value.

```
@if (item.AuditDate!= null) { @Model.AuditDate.Value.ToString("d")}
```

Googling the error that you are getting [provides this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204388/130387), which shows that the error is from using the word Model in your Html helpers.  For instance, using `@Html.DisplayFor(Model=>Model.someProperty)`.  Change these to use something else other than `Model`, for instance: `@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.someProperty)` or change the capital `M` to a lowercase `m` in these helpers.

Comment: if I used  `@Model.AuditDate.Value.ToString("d")`

`Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.`

Comment: @AbuHamzah - sounds like you are still trying to put this in the `Html.DisplayFor` helper.  Don't do that.  Also, are you sure that its throwing the error on that line and not some other property you are trying to use the `DisplayFor` helper on?

Comment: If I used `@Model...` I'm getting this error: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'

Comment: @AbuHamzah Please see the last paragraph in my updated answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [**DisplayFormat**] attribute on your view model as you want to apply this format for the whole project.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: Almost what I needed, Visual Studio did the rest for me and I neded up with 
`[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]` 
and then  
`public DateTimeOffset MyExpirationDate { get; set; }`

Answer (score 7):

@ChrisPratt's answer about the use of Display Template is wrong. The correct code to make it work is:

```
@model DateTime?

@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    @Convert.ToDateTime(Model).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
}
```

That's because [`.ToString()` for `Nullable<DateTime>` doesn't accept `Format` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9hd15ket(v=VS.110).aspx).

Answer (score 6):

For me it was enough to use

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime StartDate { set; get; }
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, but use this with caution. If you intend to propagate the format of the StartDate throughout your application then okay; otherwise, a more fine tune approach should be taken.

Answer (score 5):

I implemented the similar thing this way:

1. Use **TextBoxFor** to display date in required format and make the field ***readonly***.

```html
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.AuditDate, "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", new{@class="my-style", @readonly=true})
```

2. Give **zero outline** and **zero border** to TextBox in css.

```css
.my-style {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

And......Its done :)

Comment: But why would you do it like that?

Comment: Because any of the other methods didn't worked for me and it saved me a lot of coding. Also, the end result is readonly and has no border, so it didn't looked like a textbox.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Convert

```
 <td>@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", o.frm_dt))</td>
```

Comment: this is an excellent solution, because it allows to transform the data that comes from the model without transforming the source model.

Answer (score 3):

In View Replace this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.AuditDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
```

With:

```
@if(@Model.AuditDate.Value != null){@Model.AuditDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}
else {@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.AuditDate)}
```

Explanation: If the AuditDate value is not null then it will format the date to dd/MM/yyyy, otherwise leave it as it is because it has no value.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try simply

```
@(Model.AuditDate.HasValue ? Model.AuditDate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") : String.Empty)
```

also you can use many type of string format like
.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy")
.ToString("d") etc

Comment: getting the error: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'

Comment: if I used `@model` it does not recognize

Comment: @AbuHamzah - I was mistaken, its a capital `M` when using in the HTML page, lower case `m` when declaring.

Comment: still getting the error, please see I reply to Tommy's answer

Comment: `No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments` complaining when I use `ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")`

Answer (score 2):

After some digging and I ended up setting `Thread`'s [CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) value to have [CultureInfo("en-US")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) in the controller’s action method:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Here are some [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226514/best-place-to-set-currentculture-for-multilingual-asp-net-mvc-web-applications) if you want have this setting on every view.

About `CurrentCulture` property value:

> The [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object that is returned by this property, together
>   with its associated objects, determine the default format for dates,
>   times, numbers, currency values, the sorting order of text, casing
>   conventions, and string comparisons.

Source: [MSDN CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

*Note:*  The previous `CurrentCulture` property setting is probably optional if the controller is already running with `CultureInfo("en-US")` or similar where the date format is `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.

After setting the `CurrentCulture` property, add code block to convert the date to `"M/d/yyyy"` format in the view:

```
@{  //code block 
    var shortDateLocalFormat = "";
    if (Model.AuditDate.HasValue) {
       shortDateLocalFormat = ((DateTime)Model.AuditDate).ToString("M/d/yyyy");
       //alternative way below
       //shortDateLocalFormat = ((DateTime)Model.AuditDate).ToString("d");
    }
}

@shortDateLocalFormat
```

Above the `@shortDateLocalFormat` variable is formatted with `ToString("M/d/yyyy")` works. If `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` is used, like I did first then you end up having [leading zero issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820605/c-sharp-tostringmm-dd-yy-remove-leading-0s). Also like recommended by [Tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28114973/2048391) `ToString("d")` works as well. Actually `"d"` stands for *[“Short date pattern”](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)* and can be used with different culture/language formats too.

I guess the code block from above can also be substituted with some [cool helper method](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/787320/an-absolute-beginners-tutorial-on-html-helpers-and) or similar.

For example

```
@helper DateFormatter(object date)
{
    var shortDateLocalFormat = "";
    if (date != null) {     
        shortDateLocalFormat = ((DateTime)date).ToString("M/d/yyyy");
     }

    @shortDateLocalFormat
}
```

can be used with this helper call

```
@DateFormatter(Model.AuditDate)
```

**Update**, I found out that there’s alternative way of doing the same thing when [DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx) method is used. When this method is used then there’s no need to use `Thread`’s `CurrentCulture` property. The `CultureInfo("en-US")` is passed as second argument --> [IFormatProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) to `DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` method.

Modified helper method:

```
@helper DateFormatter(object date)
{
    var shortDateLocalFormat = "";
    if (date != null) {
       shortDateLocalFormat = ((DateTime)date).ToString("d", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
    }

    @shortDateLocalFormat
}
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yuM2nN)

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way to get a simple date string :

```
 @DateTime.Parse(Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.AuditDate).ToString()).ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Here's what this answer does: takes the `HtmlString` output by `DisplayFor`, converts it to a `String`, parses it as a `DateTime`, then formats that as a `String`. Needlessly complex, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.AuditDate)
```

Use

```
@Model.AuditDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

This style renders the date as: `06/02/2022`.

You can style your string accordingly to how you need it.

Comment: Here is what worked for me      @Model.AuditDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Answer (score 1):

You just need To set Data Annotation in your Model.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime AuditDate {get; set;}
```

On view(cshtml page)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AuditDate)
```

Nothing else you need to do.
Hope its useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my controller and here is what worked for me:

```
model.DateSigned.HasValue ? model.DateSigned.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : ""
```

"DateSigned" is the value from my model
The line reads, if the model value has a value then format the value, otherwise show nothing.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of using `@html.DisplayFor()`.

```
@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.AuditDate))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833054/how-can-i-format-a-nullable-datetime-with-tostring) about the `No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments` error.

You cannot format a nullable DateTime - you have to use the DateTime.Value property.

```
@Model.AuditDate.HasValue ? Model.AuditDate.Value.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty
```

> Tip: It is always helpful to work this stuff out in a standard class with intellisense before putting it into a view. In this case, you would get a compile error which would be easy to spot in a class.

Comment: if I use the suggested code then getting this error `'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'`