# Display DateTime "Year" as 17 and not 2017 (VB)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a `<table>` and i want in one `<td>`, to show date time like this: 04/2017
Its April, 2017:

```
<td class="card-date">
   @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.CreditCardExpirationDate.Month) +"/"+ 
   @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.CreditCardExpirationDate.Year)                                           

</td>
```

But the year is in 4 digit format, i need just 2 digits.
And i need to add zero before the month. so it be 04 and not just 4.
Thx.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRs0h.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [custom format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
item.CreditCardExpirationDate.ToString("MM\/yy")
```

Quoted from the documentation:

- `MM`: The month, from 01 through 12.
- `\/`: The literal character `/`.
- `yy`: The year, from 00 to 99.

Note: If `CreditCardExpirationDate` is a `DateTime?` instead of a `DateTime`, you'll have to use `?.ToString` instead of `.ToString`.

Since MVC does not allow you to call methods in `DisplayFor`, you need to [annotate your model property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28114874/87698) instead: (I use C# syntax, since the link in your screen shot shows that your model is written in C#.)

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:MM\/yy}")]
public DateTime CreditCardExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have that error: [link](https://s30.postimg.org/muvcorkch/Untitled.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am no VB programmer, but in C# i would use `DateTime` and the [Date Format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// assuming item.CreditCardExpirationDate is DateTime
DateTime date = item.CreditCardExpirationDate;
var month = date.ToString("MM"); // month, leading zero
var year = date.ToString("yy"); // year, two digits
```

I hope you can adapt this to VB.

Comment: They are the same in VB.NET as well. This is a Framework feature, not specific to any language