# Debugging DisplayFor Helper

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, razor, display-templates

I am trying to debug my `DisplayFor(model => model.dateOfEmp)` initally `DateTime` would display Date + time. To avoid this I added a display template with a ShortDate.

After I added a custom **shortdate**`DisplayFor` in the folder *DisplayTemplate*, it stopped emitting the default `css` class ID. So I have deleted it the template. However, it still emits the Shortdate and not the full date + time.

Question: I would like to debug this in Visual Studio, and know **how can I find out which DisplayFor is being called.**?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid displaying Date + time, you may use DateTime.ToShortDateString Method and define the format via the DisplayFormat attribute: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115051/5649051

As I tried debugging it, but it seem VS debugging tool could not step into the CSS template.