# FormatException when formatting TimeSpan number of days without leading zeroes

Tags: c#, string-formatting

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx#dSpecifier), the `d` format specifier outputs the TimeSpan.Days property. When used in the `.ToString()` method this appears to be true:

`TimeSpan.FromDays(1).ToString("%d")`

However, when used in a `String.Format`, the specifier throws an exception:

```
String.Format("{0:d}", TimeSpan.FromDays(1))

'String.Format("{0:d}", TimeSpan.FromDays(1))' threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'
    base {System.SystemException}: {"Input string was not in a correct format."}
```

The `dd` specifier works just fine, but gives a leading zero (as intended).

Why does the `d` specifier throw an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `%`:

```
string.Format("{0:%d}", TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
```

According to the article you linked (and the example you copied):

> If the "d" custom format specifier is used alone, specify "%d" so that it is not misinterpreted as a standard format string.

Answer (score 1):

Typical, no sooner have I asked the question then I find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988353/format-net-datetime-day-with-no-leading-zero?rq=1) - apparently this applies for both DateTime and TimeSpan (and probably every other format)

Answer (score 0):

My favorite site for String.Format is [Stevex](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/).

The line you should pay attention to is under Numbers

> Specifier | Type | Format | Output (Passed Double 1.42) | Output (Passed Int -12400)
>   d | Decimal (Whole number) | {0:d} | System.FormatException | -12400

[TimeSpan.FromDays(1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromdays.aspx) returns a double.  The d formatter expects a whole number and because it receives a double, a format exception is thrown.