# C# String "D" format specifier

Tags: c#

In MSDN documentation they say the "D" (or "d") format specifier is both for [decimal numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#DFormatString) and [dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988353/format-net-datetime-day-with-no-leading-zero) but in fact it only formats a date (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988353/format-net-datetime-day-with-no-leading-zero) also):

```
string.Format("{0:d}", DateTime.Now) // Works
string.Format("{0:d}", 12.998m) // Exception
```

So, why is that and when is it possible to use it to format a decimal?

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say that the `D` specifier is also for decimal numbers?

Comment: @JayGould - *format strings* are case sensitive. You would get exactly the same situation making these same calls from VB.Net, which is generally consider a case insensitive language.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, look at first table [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#DFormatString), second row, second column, it clearly say `Decimal` ;)

Comment: @Sinatr Now look at second row *third* column :) (I agree, the *name* is misleading)

Comment: Look at the column header for the second column and you see "Name". `Decimal` is the **name** of this format specifier, not the type it applies to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs you linked to are pretty clear on this point - `D` is only supported by integral types

> The "D" (or decimal) format specifier converts a number to a string of decimal digits (0-9), prefixed by a minus sign if the number is negative. **This format is supported only for integral types.**

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#DFormatString

Comment: Thank you Jamiec, I didn't notice, still a bit confusing though, in my opinion. They could have used another letter. :)

Comment: @drevis yes, having a format called "decimal" only be useful for integral types is a bit.....confusing.